# Way to get facebook API Sharer Counts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-fql, share

I was about to get the facebook video shares. I have tried the below URLs for getting the share counts, it seems to be giving the URL share counts instead of the actual video sharer counts.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/
(and) using Graph API

For example:
The below video has video share counts as 384 as of Mar29 2012
https://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=23155051776

But the above methods are giving the share counts as either 1 or 5. Please let me know the way to get the video sharer counts using API methods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, you should add your voice to the feature request bug here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/289679207771682